# firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification() returns null in iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have a React Native project and I'm using Firebase, thus using `react-native-firebase` npm package in my project to be able to handle push notifications. I followed the docs [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications). All seems fine so far except that `getInitialNotification()` function which keeps giving me `null` in iOS. Therefore, I can't check if the app is opened by notification tap. Everything works like a charm in Android though.

Any suggestions?

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    console.log(notificationOpen); // Outputs null
}
```

**SOLVED**

I solved the issue by using latest react-native (0.59.9 > 0.60.5) and react-native-firebase (5.5.4 > 5.5.6) versions.